# Determinant of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given the following matrix, is there a way to compute the determinant other than using laplace till there're $3\times3$ determinants?

\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 &1 &1&1 \\
  1 & 2 & 1& 1 &1\\
  1& 1 & 2 & 1  &1\\
 1&1 &1 &2&1\\
 1&1&1&1&-2
 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: A calculator is certainly another way... `:P`  But I'll try to think about one that you're actually looking for. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can substract the first row from every other rows and get matrix of form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 1 &1 &1&1 \\
  -1 & 1 & 0& 0 &0\\
  -1& 0 & 1 & 0  &0\\
 -1&0 &0 &1&0\\
 -1&0&0&0&-3
 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Computing the determinant is now much easier.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate that? I'm not really sure what you did there

Comment: I.e perform the row operation $R_i - R_1$ for $i \geq 2$.

Comment: Bartek subtracted the top row from each of the other rows. Are you unfamiliar with the effects of elementary row and column operations on the determinant?

Comment: Adding any row multiplied by non-zero scalar (in this case scalar is $-1$) to another row doesn't change the determinant of matrix.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$$ It has rank two and its nonzero eigenvalues have sum $1$ (the trace) and product $$\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix} + \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix} + \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix} + \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix} = -16$$

So the characteristic polynomial is $t^3 (t^2 - t - 16)$. Evaluate this at $t = -1$ and you get $$\det(-I - A) = (-1)^5 \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Also, another comment: since it appears that you are writing your characteristic polynomial as $\det(t I - A)$, I think evaluating at $t = -1$ will give you _minus_ the determinant asked for.

Comment: @WillieWong Oops again, didn't think it out far enough, writing it down should make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Call your matrix $A$ and let $J_n$ denotes the all-one matrix of size $n$. By Laplace expansion along the last row, we have
\begin{align*}
\det(A)
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^\color{red}{4}(-1)^{5+j}a_{5j}M_{5j} + 2M_{55}\right) - 4M_{55}\\
&=\det(I_5+J_5)-4\det(I_4+J_4).
\end{align*}
As $\det(aI_n+bJ_n)=a^{n-1}(a+nb)$, we get $\det(A)=6-4(5)=-14$.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward to arrive at a triangular matrix with the same determinant:

1. After the following elementary row operations:
   $$R_1\to R_1-R_2\\
   R_2\to R_2-R_3\\
   R_3\to R_3-R_4\\
   R_4\to R_4-R_5$$
   we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
2&1&1&1&1 \\
1&2&1&1&1 \\
1&1&2&1&1 \\
1&1&1&2&1 \\
1&1&1&1&-2
\end{vmatrix}
 =
\begin{vmatrix}
1&-1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1&0 \\
0&0&0&1&3 \\
1&1&1&1&-2
\end{vmatrix}
$$

2. Using the fact that $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$:
   $$
   \begin{vmatrix}
   1&-1&0&0&0 \\
   0&1&-1&0&0 \\
   0&0&1&-1&0 \\
   0&0&0&1&3 \\
   1&1&1&1&-2
   \end{vmatrix}
   =
   \begin{vmatrix}
   1&0&0&0&1 \\
   -1&1&0&0&1 \\
   0&-1&1&0&1 \\
   0&0&-1&1&1 \\
   0&0&0&3&-2
   \end{vmatrix}
   $$
3. We then achieve an upper-triangular matrix with the following operations:
   $$
   R_2\to R_2+R_1\\
   R_3\to R_3+R_2\\
   R_4\to R_4+R_3\\
   R_5\to R_5-3R_4\\
   \begin{vmatrix}
   1&0&0&0&1 \\
   -1&1&0&0&1 \\
   0&-1&1&0&1 \\
   0&0&-1&1&1 \\
   0&0&0&3&-2
   \end{vmatrix}
   =
   \begin{vmatrix}
   1&0&0&0&1 \\
   0&1&0&0&2 \\
   0&0&1&0&3 \\
   0&0&0&1&4 \\
   0&0&0&0&-14
   \end{vmatrix}
   $$

And now, since we are tip-toeing around the Laplace transform, we shall use the following 4 facts:

- If matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ differ by only one column, say $\mathbf c_A$, $\mathbf c_B$ and $\mathbf c_C$, such that $\mathbf c_C=\mathbf c_A+\mathbf c_B$, then $\det(C)=\det(A)+\det(B)$.
- The determinant of a matrix $B$ which is obtained by multiplying a single row in matrix $A$ by a scalar $k$ is equal to $k\det(A)$.
- Since the determinant of a product of matrices is equal to the product of determinants of those matrices and $I=I^2$, we have $\det(I)=\det(I^2)=\det^2(I)\Rightarrow1=\det(I)$.
- The determinant of a singular matrix is $0$.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-14
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-13
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$=
-\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-12
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
=-1
-\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-11
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
=-2
-\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&-10
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$
\dots
$$
$$
=-14
+
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&2 \\
0&0&1&0&3 \\
0&0&0&1&4 \\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{vmatrix}
=-14+0=-14
$$

Comment: Laplase $\to$ Laplace